# Unidentified jquery problem with accordion list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to include accordion list [from here](https://codepen.io/kjbrum/pen/JKwByJ) to a simple website but I'm having problem with jquery - javascript requires jquery 2.2.4, but the site already has jquery-1.11.2.min. Adding proper jquery version with no conflict mode doesn't make javascript work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_2_2_4 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Also, adding no conflict mode to jquery 1_11_2 crashes website.

The code doesn't work on the website (pol - built co uk) but it works here perfectly even on jquery 1.11.2... Including another jquery-1.12.1.min.js in body doesn't help. 
What should I do to make it work fine without crashing the site? (I'm not its owner or webmaster) Is there an easy way to simplify javascript below to work without jquery? I tried [closure compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) but it was useless.

```js
$('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Add the correct active class
    if($(this).closest('.accordion-item').hasClass('active')) {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');

        // Add the active class
        $(this).closest('.accordion-item').addClass('active');
    }

    // Show the content
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.slideToggle(100);
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).slideUp('fast');
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font: 14px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  width: 690px;
  border-color: #a10900;
  border-width: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 75rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.accordion-item {
  position: relative;
}
.accordion-item.active .heading {
  color: white;
}
.accordion-item.active .icon {
  background: #a10900;
}
.accordion-item.active .icon:before {
  background: white;
}
.accordion-item.active .icon:after {
  width: 0;
}
.accordion-item .heading {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: lightgrey;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 4rem;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .accordion-item .heading {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
.accordion-item .heading:hover {
  color: white;
}
.accordion-item .heading:hover .icon:before, .accordion-item .heading:hover .icon:after {
  background: white;
}
.accordion-item .icon {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  border: 2px solid #a10900;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.accordion-item .icon:before, .accordion-item .icon:after {
  content: '';
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.accordion-item .icon:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
.accordion-item .content {
  display: none;
  color: #f9f9f9;
}
.accordion-item .content p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .accordion-item .content {
    line-height: 1.75;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordion-item">
        <a href="#" class="heading">
            <div class="icon"></div>
            <div class="title"> <span style="color:#a10900">Accordion item 1</div>
        </a>
        <div class="content">
            <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The html structure in the codepen and the one in your website is different. That is why the accordion is not working. Did you change it for any purpose?

Comment: That's the problem, thanks! The wysiwyg editor is messing up the code, even when I edit the source code and it's driving me nuts for few hours... 
The problem is, the outer <a> or <span> goes automatically inside divs, like that:

`  <div class="icon"></div>
    <div>
  <div class="title"><a class="heading" href="#">Accordion item 1</a></div>`
that's the problematic fragment.

so I'm trying to wrap it all into <div class="heading"> but it works partially. Could you help me with changing classes/js so that it would work?

Comment: But the html structure is intact for the first `.accordion-item`. For the rest, it has changed. Could be due to some mistake in the html you gave. Like a missing closing tag or something. Try to fix that. Otherwise it would be difficult to make the event handler work for two different html structures.

Comment: thanks for reply. I've managed to change the first item - it is possilbe through code editor but I have to do all this corrections every time I open the editor. What's more - that still somehow doesn't work